# Add blocked (via robots.txt) URLs in Sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, google-search, google-search-console

In my sitemap there are some links which I don't want Google to index, so I blocked them using robots.txt.

Now in Google Webmaster Tool, it is showing warnings. Will it adversely impact my website in Google?

Comment: Why do you have these URLs in the sitemap if you don't want them crawled? The purpose of an XML sitemap is (normally) to provide search engines with a list of URLs that you want them to crawl. Is there some issue preventing you from editing the sitemap?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google’s interpretation/behaviour.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to remove these URLs from *XML sitemap*.